# How to create a list of topics in Apache Kafka using single command

Tags: unix, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

As of now I am creating a topic one by one by using below command.

```
sh ./bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181  --topic sdelivery --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

Since I have 200+ topics to be created. Is there any way to create a list of topic with a single command?

I am using 0.10.2 version of Apache Kafka.

Answer (score 7):

This seems like more of a unix/bash question than a Kafka one: the xargs utility is specifically designed to run a command repeatedly from a list of arguments. In your specific case you could use:

```bash
cat topic_list.txt | \
  xargs -I % -L1 sh ./bin/kafka-topics \
    --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --topic % \
    --replication-factor 1 \
    --partitions 1
```

If you want to do a "dry run" and see what commands will be executed you can replace the `sh` with `echo sh`.

Alternatively you can just make sure that your config files have default topic settings of `--replication-factor 1` and `--partitions 1` and just allow those topics to be automatically created the first time you send a message to them.

Comment: The answer specifies `-I % -L1`, but manual says it's not correct combination `The options --max-lines (-L, -l), --replace (-I, -i) and --max-args (-n) are mutually exclusive.`.

Answer (score 7):

You could [use Terraform](https://github.com/Mongey/terraform-provider-kafka) or [Kubernetes Operators](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/in-development/overview.html#overview-concepts-topic-operator-str) which will not only help you create topics (with one command), but also *manage* them later if you did need to delete or modify their configs.

But without custom solutions, and only for purpose of batch-creation, you can use `awk` for this

Create a file

```
$ cat /tmp/topics.txt
test1:1:1
test2:1:2
```

Then use AWK `system` function to execute the kafka-topics script, and parse the file

```bash
awk -F':' '{ system("./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic=" $1 " --replication-factor=" $2 --partitions=" $3 " ) }' /tmp/topics.txt
Created topic "test1".
Created topic "test2".
```

And we can see the topics are created

```
$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
test1
test2
```

Note: Hundreds of topics this quickly might overload Zookeeper, so might help to add a call to `"; sleep 10"` at the end.

As of Kafka 3.0, the Zookeeper flag is replaced by bootstrap-servers.