# kafka topic configuration using properties file

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I want to configure Kafka with some topics and their unique retention settings. so when I start Kafka it will load the server.properties file with those settings.

The only way I found was by starting Kafka, and then start and configure topics using `kafka-topics.sh` script.

Example:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --alter --topic as-access --config retention.ms=86400000
```

I am using Kafka over docker, so instead of setting the entry point to be the actual script that start Kafka, I need to create my own script which will start Kafka and run some shell commands to configure those topics.
Also if I need to create those topics on my own, I need to start and create some logic regarding topics which already exist. and I prefer not to go that road.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I just came across the same question.

Answer (score 0):

> need to create my own script which will start Kafka and run some shell commands to configure those topics

1. `wurstmeister/kafka` already supports `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` environment variable for this purpose
2. It is recommended you use a second "init container", (or shell script around `docker run/compose`) that waits for the other kafka container to start and be healthy, then do topic-creation. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52529671/2308683)
3. Just use AdminClient API in your client code to create topics before running producers or consumers.