# Apache Kafka : Delete topics in bulk

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a scenario, where we need to delete multiple kafka topics across clusters the count of topics are >1k in each cluster. How can we do it from CLI? I understand that we can have comma separated topics names with the `--delete --topic <topic1>,<topic2>,...`  however we have these topic names in a file already shared by customer. Can we do some sort of a loop and delete them one-by-one in a cli command/script?
In the outset it seems quite trivial; however I am no able to come to any definitive strategy to do it. Can someone please help with some pseudo code or a working one would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the CLI doesn't accept a list.

So yes, write a simple bash or [AWK script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52529671/2308683) (or programming language of your choice) to loop over the file. Or mentioned in linked post, convert your file to a Terraform HCL definition with Kafka provider, then you could `terraform destroy`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Just a follow up question to the awk solution, on your comment in the other chat; so you mentioned to add a sleep 10, so as not to overload the zookeeper. Would it be a wise option to add it for the delete as well?

Comment: Deletion is asynchronous anyway, but adding a sleep wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 0):

Posting my script here; hope it helps someone else

```
#!/bin/bash
raw_file=$1 
sed -i '/^$/d' ${raw_file}
count=1
while read topics; do
    # reading each line    
    echo "`date +%c`"
    echo "#${count}:Deleting Topic:${topics}"
    ./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-servers <HostName>:<Port> --delete --topic $topics
    status=$?
    [ $status -eq 0 ] && echo "${topics}:SUCCESS"|tee -a ${raw_file}-status || echo "${topics}:FAILURE"|tee -a ${raw_file}-status
    echo "========================================================================="
    count=$[$count+1]
done < ${raw_file}
```

In some instances when brokers are not available due to some reason, we could do it from zookeepers as well.

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <hostName>:<port> --delete --topic $topics
```

This will not delete it instantly however mark it to deletion, and then when the broker leader connects with the zookeeper, it will copy metadata and there after actually delete the topics.